# htaccess for sub_directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have site in production with own .htaccess file :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ portfolio.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^companies$ companies.php [NC]
```

I created demo_version of new site in the subdirectory my_site.com/demo_site, and i want to write rules in my_site.com htaccess rewrite rules for subdirectory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

How can i split this rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep first part of .htaccess shown in root .htaccess and keep this in `/demo_site/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /demo_site/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```